# How to get my private repositories in github using github3 library?

Tags: github, github-api, github3.py, pygithub

I have generated a github access token. I've tried to access the repos from pygithub and also github api v3, stuff was fine.

Now using github3 I cannot access my private repos. I am using python(I know that you know).

```
repos = github3.login(token=get_github_token()).repositories_by('myusername')
```

Code structure feels like I am trying to access some one else's private repos. 
Its not the same way in pygithub. In pygithub you can get your own repos without passing the username.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close to a solution, you just need a slightly different method:

```
gh = github3.login(token=get_github_token())
for repos in gh.repositories():
    ...
```

As you noticed `repositories_by` is for listing another user's *public* repositories. Also `all_repositories` is used to list all *public* repositories on GitHub. But `repositories` requires you to be authenticated and allows you to list which repositories you want, e.g.,

```
gh.repositories(type='all')
gh.repositories(type='owner')
gh.repositories(type='member')
gh.repositories(type='private')
gh.repositories(type='public')
```